# show month and date in two digits using R

Tags: r, digits

I have a column in numeric format as below.

```
col1:
9302014  (September 30, 2014)
10312014 (October 31, 2014)
1212014  (December 01, 2014)
1212014  (January 21, 2014)
```

I need to convert the month and date column in col1 to two digits. How can I achieve this in R.

```
Output:
09302014
10312014
12012014
```

Comment: Question: Is `1212014` December 1st or January 21?  Please clarify the meaning of your data.

Comment: Please see the edits above.

Comment: OK, but then what does January 21, 2014 look like?

Comment: I don't have January 21, 2014 in my data set.

Comment: Fair enough, but I think you do still have an encoding problem here, in the sense that we may not be able to cleanly resolve a given number string back to a single date.

Comment: Can you show an example of your desired output?